# connection.prepareStatement("alter session set container=YPDB2").executeUpdate() return 0;

Tags: session, jdbc, oracle12c, alter

use ojbc7 to connection oracle12c, 
execute "alter session set container=ypdb2", it seems not work;

but i use sqlplus to execute, it is work;

here is my code;

```
OracleDataSource oracleDataSource = new OracleDataSource();
oracleDataSource.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/orcl");
Connection connection = oracleDataSource.getConnection("sys as sysdba", "123456");
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("alter session set container=YPDB2");
log.info("{}",preparedStatement.executeUpdate());
```

console print 0
it seems to affect the zero row;

Does this mean that the “alter” did not succeed?

Comment: Exactly what is your question? Does something not work? If so how does it not work? Also, please read the apidoc of [`PreparedStatement.execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute--) for the meaning of `false`. If after reading that you still have a question, please **ask an explicit question**.

Comment: thanks your advise.

Comment: And after the update, I suggest that you read the apidoc of [`PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--), specifically (emphasis mine): _"Returns: either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements **or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing**"_

Comment: Why do you want to do `alter session set container` instead of directly connecting to the PDB using `usr/pwd@ypdb2` ?

Comment: Because I want to connect to CDB to create PDB and modify system parameters of PDB, such as CPU_COUNT, SPG and so on. with ALTER SESSION, this can be done in a single connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems a bug of ojbc;

```
@Test
public void testAlterSession() throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource oracleDataSource = new OracleDataSource();
    oracleDataSource.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/ypdb9");
    Connection sys_as_sysdba_connection = oracleDataSource.getConnection("sys as sysdba", "123456");
    int i = sys_as_sysdba_connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("alter session set container=ypdb9");
    log.info("i:{}",i);
    List<Map<String, Object>> maps = OdbcUtil.resultSetToList(sys_as_sysdba_connection.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from v$pdbs"));
    maps.forEach(map->log.info("{}",map));
    sys_as_sysdba_connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("alter session set container=cdb$root");
    List<Map<String,Object>> maps2 = OdbcUtil.resultSetToList(sys_as_sysdba_connection.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from v$pdbs"));
    maps2.forEach(map->log.info("{}",map));
}
```

In this test, "excuteUpdate(sql)" returns 0,but the "container" does change when I select the pdb again;

i don't know why yet;